# Calling a method within a plugin function and need to know the object name of this?

Tags: jquery

I tried the following without success inside a working plugin method...

```
get_List: function () {
    alert(this.prop("nodeName")); // prop is not a function
    alert(this.prop("tagName")); // prop is not a function
    alert(this[0].nodeName); // this[0] is undefined; 
}
```

Comment: Do you get any errors?  What is your question?

Comment: Error messages were provided along with the question. Once again, the question how do you get object name of this variable....

Comment: I updated my answer with a working fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

Use Tested [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Cyberjetx/UcyWy/)

```
$(this).attr('id');
```

to get a ref to the current object in jQuery.

```
<a href="#" id="lnkClix" class="clickme">click</a>
<br>
<a href="#" id="lnkCliK" class="clickyou">click</a>
```

the js:

```
var $cm = $('.clickme').click(function(e){
  alert($cm.selector + ' - ' + $cm.attr('id') ); 
});

$('.clickyou').click(function(e){
  alert($(this).attr('id') ); 
});
```

Comment: this.name would be a more complete answer sorry. I have updated the answer.

Comment: Still not working, getting an empty output. Tried $(this).name and this.name. I know for sure this is an object, tested by typeof this with output object..